# iPhone: Setting navigationItem button's width property

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I have been trying to get around setting navigationitem button's width property but couldn't find a way to get it done what exactly I am looking for.

Following code works fine setting button size what I want and appear nicely but I don't see actually button, its rather only my image. It should appear like button and it has background image!

```
UIButton *addCommentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addCommentButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
[addCommentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addComment) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addCommentButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addCommentButton];
```

Following code does that, but I can't set button size (25,25)!!

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addComment)];
```

I tried setting width explicitly but it does make no difference!

[[self.navigationItem rightBarButtonItem] setWidth] = 25;

Can someone please help me to sort out this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a quick explanation to fix your issue, but I think the code posted in the following link will help you solve it.

[Customization of UINavigationBar and the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066874/customization-of-uinavigationbar-and-the-back-button/7068222#7068222)

Comment: Thanks. That exact code doesn't work for me but I got an idea how to get my things done and implemented! I really surprised by the amount of code I need to integrate to just get a round button with image!! or just resizing the rightbarbutton item!

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet generates a custom button, which won't have a "button" look and feel. The second code snippet gives a UIBarButtonItem with a bordered UIBarButtonItem style (not a UIButton). Using the first code snippet, just create a UIButton with a button type RoundedRect instead of Custom.

Comment: I tried roundedrect as well. It doesn't allow me to specify background color! I want to create the same button in my second code snippet but want to resize it!